# Install FREENAS on ORACLE SUN SPARC T5240

Tags: storage-area-network, oracle, truenas, sun, sparc

is possible to install FreeNas server on Sun Sparc Enterprise T5240 (Hardware compatibility),and how to do that?
Thanks

Comment: In my point of View, if you cant find it on the freenas Page or on Google i belive no

Comment: No. This HW is not supported. See [FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE Hardware Notes](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.2R/hardware.html#proc-sparc64).

Comment: @djdomi u know the human like to testing and discovering

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as [@Vladimir Botka](https://serverfault.com/users/382981/vladimir-botka) is not possible as [FreeNas 11.2 version](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.2R/hardware.html#proc-sparc64) look like as alternative could be [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Sparc64)/ with [ProxMox Ve](https://www.proxmox.com/en/proxmox-ve) for virtualization.

Comment: that could be an Option and rum from there freenas